# Asking interviewer out on a casual lunch date

Tags: interviewing, socializing

I have recently attended an interview; it went on pretty well. Both of us liked the technical discussion and I was offered a job too. But, I rejected it as the salary negotiation with the HR was not up to my expectations.

I was very impressed with the technical interviewer; he was smart, cool, composed, accommodating and I really started liking him. It's been a week, but I am really unable to get him out of my mind.

Generally, I do not go out on dates nor do I get easily impressed. I am a tough nut to crack. But, this person was different.

Now that I do not have anything to do with that company, I was wondering if I could ask him out on a casual lunch date. I wanted to know what would be the repercussions and how should I proceed if I ever have to?

Also, I do not wish to get romantically involved with this person. It's just a casual lunch date that I want to have with him. I have no idea about his marital status or relationship status.

Or, should I drop this idea?

Comment: 1) You don't need to defend your personality here 2) I still don't understand what your aim is given that you stress you don't wish to get romantically involved with him. Could you specify your objectives?

Comment: @385703 Just lunch. That is just an excuse as there is no better option. Meet him once more, casually.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Why do you want to meet him? Are you interested in him romantically or not? If not, why do you want to meet him?

Comment: _Meet him once more_ for what purpose? Business? Personal?  You want to have lunch with him for nothing? You need to understand everybody's time is precious including yours. Please make your question clear

Comment: Now that consensus is "It's OK to go out", you should consider taking this question to https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com if you need more suggestions

Comment: @aaaaaa I posted the question at IPS, initially. I was asked to post it here since it is workplace related; deleted the question from there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not 'Loveline with Dr. Drew'.

Comment: @JimG. don't be mean. There are at least few Q here "is it OK to ask out interviewer"

Comment: Topicality aside, you should probably be honest about your intentions here, at least with yourself if not with us. It's rather strange to stress having no romantic interest while still mentioning things like flirting and being unable to stop thinking of someone...

Comment: "It's been a week, but I am really unable to get him out of my mind" does not really gel with "I do not wish to get romantically involved with this person"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more of a personal rather than a Workplace related question.

Comment: The question should be clarified. On the Workplace we could answer if you're asking your former interview for lunch is ethical, but we need to understand your intent for doing so to best inform you on the ethics of the situation.

Comment: I think the urge to have lunch with him has come down. But, as @Kilisi suggested I shall opt for getting in touch with him through social media. And as Joe has suggested, it is best to avoid lunch etc, if I intend to join the company in the future. I cannot predict if I am going to join there or not in the future; but there is always a chance, may be in the future. Why spoil it? So, totally going with the social media suggestion.

Comment: @Snow Why? I wanted to know the aftermath of it in case I choose to go out on lunch.

Comment: @jcmack intent was simple. I was totally impressed by him in the interview, esp with the knowledge that he had and that he was accommodating. It lingered in my mind for a while; but it has subsided now. Intent was to build more rapport with him; but, I, now understand that it is best to use social media for that purpose. Yeah, I wanted to know if it would have been professional, ethical or not too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Get his contact number, reintroduce yourself and and ask him.

One problem though is you express no romantic interest, yet this will be the impression whatever you say. Particularly since you want to meet him in person in a neutral environment. If it's just discussing ideas and things then it is probably better to get to know him through social media or something like that at least initially. I communicate and share ideas with a lot of people I never personally meet.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I think I'll go with the social media thing.

Comment: Good luck, good, interesting people are worth getting to know.

Answer (score 9):

> I was wondering if I could ask him out on a casual lunch date. I
>   wanted to know what would be the repercussions and how should I
>   proceed if I ever have to?

As long as you are no longer connected with the company, and don't wish to be in the future, there are no issues here.

Just email or call.

If you may want to get a job at this company in the future, then avoid this approach.